# Nuxt Axios Error on build Request failed with status code 429

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

When building my Nuxt.js project I get the following error

```
12:16:11 PM: [error] Request failed with status code 429
12:16:11 PM:   at createError (node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
12:16:11 PM:   at settle (node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
12:16:12 PM:   at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:269:11)
12:16:12 PM:   at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:525:35)
12:16:12 PM:   at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1358:12)
12:16:12 PM:   at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

I know that I am reaching the rate limit of an API endpoint I am using. In production, it is fine because those API requests are used on multiple subpages. But having those errors means that my build takes way longer than I would like (and this adds more cost).

I tried:

- Called the API endpoint on mounted which is the last [Nuxt Lifecycle](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/nuxt-lifecycle/)
- Using try-catch

**What can I do to prevent Nuxt generate/build to request those API endpoints?** I only need them when a visitor visits the page in production.

1. Could I use some kind of cache?
2. Can I skip those API requests on build?

Thank you very much :)